# RSS: moving CMS content between categories

Tags: rss

I have a client that is using the ExpressionEngine CMS. Up until recently, they had one blog with an RSS feed. They then created a second blog, with its own RSS feed. They now want to move some of the older posts in the original blog over to the second blog, as they fit better in the second blog.

My question is this: if we just re-categorize the blog posts, are these older posts going to show up in the second blog's RSS feed, and if they do, will they appear as new posts?

Answer (score 0):

There are three main reasons why older posts may show up as new in a feed reader:

1. The GUID or permalink to the post has changed from what it was before
2. The post was not previously in the RSS, regardless of its date
3. The `pubDate` has changed indicating a new item compared to the existing cache

Most aggregators look at the GUID or permalink first to determine uniqueness of item and whether or not to have it show up as new. If neither of those are present they may fall back to the `pubDate` element.

Just changing the text or category of the post usually doesn't send out a signal that the post is new.

Unless of course changing the category also means it turns up in another RSS feed, as in your case, in which case, it will show up as new no matter when you posted it.